# Efficient Android Design and Use of Classes

Tags: java, android, performance, android-activity

I don't have any code I need help with, but instead I have a question about android design in general. In the game I am making, I have an activity class, but all I use it for is getting resources (which are passed to the view class) and creating a view class, which handles all of the game logic, controls, display, etc. It doesn't seem efficient to only use the activity class to load all of my data just to be passed to another class or to rely on the view class to do all of the work, so what is the best way to use view and activity classes?

Comment: I don't see the problem in having small classes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not necessarily wrong to do it your way.  The thing that makes me leery that you said is having lots of logic in the view.  Android is really set up for an MVC architecture, and there's a lot of advantages to following that.  The Activity is more or less the controller, and the various Views are the view.  When I hear about a lot of logic in view classes it makes me worries that your behavior is very tightly coupled with your graphical representation, which will make expanding or changing the layout difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still learning android and I hadn't heard of the MVC architecture before, but it seems better organized than how I'm operating now, so I'll be sure to use it in my next project.